# Validating Plone 3.2.1 BrowserView

Tags: paypal, plone

I have written a simple add-on browserview for a Plone 3.2.1 site, it is a simple form that uses [HTML variables specified by PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) and then posts to a PayPal address.

Due to the nature of these fields on the PayPal form, there is absolutely no validation when I post directly to PayPal, this is understandable as most of them are optional. I am looking to use urllib and urllib2 in order so that I can instead post the form to a Python script, validate the input and and then post to PayPal.

### Layout of BrowserView (trimmed)

```
paypal.test
|-paypal
  |-test
    |-browser
      |-paypal_validation.py
      |-paypal_validation_script.py
      |-paypal_view.pt
      |-configure.zcml
```

### configure.zcml

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    i18n_domain="paypal.test">

    ...

    <browser:page
        name="paypal_validation_script"
        for="*"
        permission="zope2.View"
        class=".paypal_validation.PayPalValidation"
        />
    <browser:page 
        name="paypal_validation"
        for="*"
        permission="zope2.View"
        class=".paypal_validation.PayPalView"
        />
</configure>
```

### paypal_validation.py

```
from Products.Five import BrowserView
from Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile import ViewPageTemplateFile

class PayPalView(BrowserView):

  template = ViewPageTemplateFile('paypal_view.pt')

  def __call__(self):
    self.paypal_name = getattr(self.context, 'paypal_name', 'World')
    return self.template()
```

### paypal_view.pt

```
<form action="paypal_validation_script" method="post" 
  tal:define="did python:request.form['did'];
              ourl string:http://www.mysite.co.uk/uploadedfiles/;
              dil python:ourl + did">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal-facilitator@someothersite.co.uk" />
  <label for="item_name">Design Name:</label>
  <input name="item_name" id="item_name" />
  <label for="dimensionx">Width (mm):</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Width (mm)" />
  <input id="dimensionx" name="os0" />
  <label for="dimensiony">Height (mm):</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Height (mm)" />
  <input id="dimensiony" name="os1" />
  <label for="dimensionz">Depth (mm):</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Depth (mm)" />
  <input id="dimensionz" name="os2" />
  <label for="design_no">Design Number:</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Design Number" />
  <input id="design_no" name="os3" />
  <label for="tool_no">Tool/Cutter Number:</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="on4" value="Tool/Cutter Number" />
  <input id="tool_no" name="os4" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" id="item_number" tal:attributes="value dil"/>
  <label for="street_addr">Street Address:</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="on5" value="Street Address" />
  <input id="street_addr" name="os5" />
  <label for="city">City:</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="on6" value="City" />
  <input id="city" name="os6" />
  <label for="postcode">Post Code:</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="on7" value="Post Code" />
  <input id="postcode" name="os7" />
  <label for="tel">Telephone Number:</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="on8" value="Telephone" />
  <input id="tel" name="os8" />
  <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="on9" value="Email Address" />
  <input id="email" name="os9" />
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="19.99" />
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mysite.co.uk" />
  <div class="formControls">
    <input type="submit" data-env="sandbox" value="Pay with PayPal" />
  </div>
</form>
```

### paypal_validation_script.py

This is currently empty as I have so far been unable to get this working... I presume I can just use `context.REQUEST` here to obtain filed information?

### What is happening

Whenever I submit the form I am taken to a 404 explaining that paypal_validation_script is not available, I'm not sure how I can reference this script (see above) in my form so that I can validate and post the necessary information using it.

Comment: What is the complete URL of the 404 page you get? In the `/paypal_validation_script` called on a proper Plone context?

Comment: @keul I get `http://example.com/paypal_validation_script`

Comment: There's something strange: you define the view as being inside the `paypal_validation.PayPalValidation`, but then you also talk of a `paypal_validation_script` file (empty?). How is the code of the `PayPalValidation` class?

Comment: @keul That's the bit I'm stuck on along with getting the form input to be processed by that paypal_validation_script file, I can't seem to find much documentation  for validating form input that's not coming from a content type field. Currently the paypal_validation_script is empty

Comment: what I mean is that definition of `paypal_validation.PayPalValidation` is missing from your question. Maybe the error is there.